# Jquery Add class to next image in <td> tag using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

How can jQuery be used to add class to next image?

[image]

I have set of images in webpage using for loop. They are displayed in table rows.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <?php
    <td><img class="img1" src="http://s5.tinypic.com/30v0ncn_th.jpg"/></td>

    for ($x = 0; $x < 5; $x++) { ?>
      <td>
        <img class="loopimg" src="http://s5.tinypic.com/30v0ncn_th.jpg"/>
      </td>
    <?php  } ?>
</table>
```

What I would like to achieve is when i click on first image (class="img1"), it add class to the next image , clicking on that would add class to the next image.

```
$('.img1').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().next("td").addClass("active");
  alert("class");
});
```

This Jquery code add "active" class to next `<td>` tag, i would like class to be added to next image. Thank you in advance

Comment: [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com)

Comment: You have a misplaced `<?php` tag.  It should be after the `<td><img class="img1" ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

while your next tag is a td and you want to add class to it's child image you have to use the children function of jquery library like this

```
  $(document).ready(function(){     
            $('.img1').click(function(){

         $(this).parent().next("td").children( "img" ).addClass("active");

        alert("class");
        });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly note that your HTML is invalid as you need to have a `<tr>` wrapping all the `<td>`.

To solve your issue you can get the parent `tr` from the clicked `img` element, then find the first `.loopimg` element within that, like this:

```
$('.img1').click(function(){
  $(this).closest('tr').find('.loopimg:first').addClass("active");
});
```

There are also some major issues with your PHP syntax - however I'm going to assume these are just caused by you transcribing the code to the question, as it wouldn't work at all in its current state.

Answer (score 1):

Add class to td children:

```
$('.table .img').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().next("td").children('img').addClass("active");
    alert("class");
});
```

I change selector to **.table .img** to work with any table image.